# C++: some errors about const char* and printf

Tags: c++, dll

I found this code for reading data from my USB peripheral:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#define IWEARDRV_EXPLICIT
#include <windows.h>
#include <iweardrv.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // Load functions dynamically (in case they don't have a VR920)
    HINSTANCE iweardll = LoadLibraryA("iweardrv.dll");
    if (!iweardll) {
        printf("VR920 drivers are not installed, you probably don't have a VR920.");
        return 2;
    }

    IWROpenTracker = (PIWROPENTRACKER) GetProcAddress(iweardll, "IWROpenTracker");
    IWRCloseTracker = (PIWRCLOSETRACKER) GetProcAddress(iweardll, "IWRCloseTracker");
    IWRZeroSet = (PIWRZEROSET) GetProcAddress(iweardll, "IWRZeroSet");
    IWRGetTracking = (PIWRGETTRACKING) GetProcAddress(iweardll, "IWRGetTracking");
    IWRGetVersion = (PIWRGETVERSION) GetProcAddress(iweardll, "IWRGetVersion");

    // Try to connect to the VR920 tracker
    if (IWROpenTracker()) {
        printf("VR920 is not connected.");
        return 1;
    }

    // Read 20 samples
    for (int i=1; i<=20; i++) {
        LONG y, p, r;
        double yaw, pitch, roll;
        if (!IWRGetTracking(&y,&p,&r)) {
            yaw = y*(180.0/32768.0);
            pitch = p*(180.0/32768.0);
            roll = r*(180.0/32768.0);
            printf("Yaw=%lf degrees, Pitch=%lf degrees, Roll=%lf degrees", yaw, pitch, roll);
        } else {
            printf("Unable to read tracking.");
        }   
    Sleep(500);
    }   

    // Tidy up
    IWRCloseTracker();
    FreeLibrary(iweardll);
    return 0;
}
```

Where I've setted additional include directory for include file `iweardrv.h`. It returns me these errors:

```
IntelliSense: argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"
IntelliSense: identifier "printf" is undefined
```

How do I avoid the errors? First error refers to `LoadLibrary` argument `"iweardrv.dll"` (a dynamic Library related to `iweardrv.h`) and second error refers to all `printf` calling lines.

EDIT: I corrected the first error using `LoadLibraryA()` because it takes a `const char*` but I cannot correct the second error.

Comment: Your code was double-spaced and not indented, which made it very difficult to read. (That may have been an artifact of the way you copied it into the web form.) I've fixed it for you.

Answer (score 1):

The first error is because you are compiling with UNICODE defined and LoadLibrary expects a wide string. Use the L prefix to specify a wide literal:

```
LoadLibrary(L"iweardrv.dll");
```

The second error is due to a missing #include. You need to include stdio.h to define printf:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

For C++ it would be more normal to use std::cout rather than printf.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I include studio but now it returns:Error 1 error C1083: Cannot open precompiled header file: 'Debug\file.pch': No such file or directory

Comment: I think I answered the question you asked. Myself, for a quick lash up like this, I would not use precompiled headers, and I would not use stdafx.h.